# Relational view of phpmyadmin stops at the "loading" message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having problems opening the `relational view` of `phpmyadmin`. The problem more concisely is that once I click on `relational view` the website keeps hanging on the `loading... message` I've read around and theoreticaly speaking it should work as I am using `InnoDB`.

Please see pictures below.

What am i missing?

[image][image]